# Loadbalancer SSL Termination & secure cookie

Tags: security, ssl, cookies, load-balancing

I need some clarity regarding load balancer ssl termination.

I have the following deployment overview:

*CLIENT ->(https)-> [LB] ->(http)-> { app001 | app002 | appNNN }*

I have a new requirement to access a secure cookie set by the client user agent in one of my back-end servers which are located behind a load balancer.

I understand the the secure cookie must be transmitted over ssl but if the load balancer terminates ssl will the cookie be passed/visable to the backend servers ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it will be passed through to your web server even though the communication between your LB and Web server will be over HTTP. The client will not know that this is the case and believes it is communicating via HTTPS.

The secure cookie flag is observed by the browser and tells the browser to only send the cookie if the communication is via HTTPS. Since the client sets up its communication to the LB (which is over HTTPS) the client believes it is going via HTTPS and the cookie will be sent.